# Javascript ES6 How to convert a const function to a function

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuexfire

Trying to use vuexfire for Firebase bindings, the documentation state to insert the following action for binding

```
const setTodosRef = firebaseAction(({ bindFirebaseRef, unbindFirebaseRef }, { ref }) => {
  // bunding will automatically unbind any previously bound ref so you
  // don't need to unbind before binding over an existing bound key
  bindFirebaseRef('todos', ref)
  // it is possible to unbind a bound key at any time
  unbindFirebaseRef('todos')
})
```

In my store root.js , all the actions are written with the following pattern

```
/**
 * Import Dependency
 */
import * as types from './mutation_types'
import i18n from '@/locales'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import { firebaseMutations, firebaseAction } from 'vuexfire'

setTodosRef ( ) {
  bindFirebaseRef('todos', ref)
  unbindFirebaseRef('todos')
}
```

How can I pass the parameters to the function ? 
in order to call

```
this.$store.dispatch('setTodosRef', db.ref('todos'))

setTodosRef (firebaseAction(({ bindFirebaseRef, unbindFirebaseRef }, { ref }))  { ... }
```

doesn't work...

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected "," (119:29)
```

thanks for feedback

UPDATE

I removed the syntax error using

```
  setTodosRef: firebaseAction(({ bindFirebaseRef, unbindFirebaseRef }, ref) => {
    bindFirebaseRef('todos', ref)
    unbindFirebaseRef('todos')
  })
```

but I am not sure that's correct... ?

Answer (score 0):

Your store actions are going to take two arguments. The first is a context object passed by vuex and is typically dereferenced. I don't have all of your code, so I can't write an exact method for you, but it needs to be something like this (assuming es6):

```
setTodosRef({ commit }, todos) {
  commit(types.SET_TODOS, { todos })
}
```

Then you would have a mutation that handles the commit. It also receives an injected parameter as the first argument from vuex, then you provide the data in the second argument like:

```
[types.SET_TODOS](state, { todos }) {
  state.todos = todos
}
```

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html